# How to get the selected item from UL using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a tab control using Ul and Divs. Ul is used to display the tab heads. When the user selects one Tab (ie , 'Li') ,the tab back color get changed with respect to others.

I want to get the Selected and not selected li in that Ul .

I used

```
 $(".tab li:selected").css("background-color","red");
 $(".tab li:deselected").css("background-color","white");
```

It 's not working, I know the code does not work .just guess it.
 Now may you understood my problem,right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your user selects a tab, add a class to that tab that represents this:

```
$('.tab li').click(function() {
    ... // your existing code
    $('.tab li').removeClass('selected'); // removes the "selected" class from all tabs
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // adds it to the one that's just been clicked
}
```

Then, in your CSS, you can style it as necessary.

```
.tab li {
    background-color: white;
}

.tab li.selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select a tab, you basically **click** it, so you can do like this:

```
 $('.tab li').click(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color","red");
   $(this).css("background-color","white");
 });
```

Now `$(this)` refers to your selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

```
$(".tab li").click(function() {
    $(".tab li").css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

**Edit:** the `:selected` selector works only for selectable items, such as `<option>`s inside of `<select>`s.