# How to change the color of listitem depending on the link inside state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, menu

Q:

I have the following menu:

I want to change the color of the list item if the link  in `active` state. How to do that?

## my.aspx :

```
        <div style="height: 50px">
            <ul id="topnav" style="text-align: center">
                <li><a href="MasterData.aspx">1111</a></li>
                <li><a href="ScheduleForm.aspx">2222 </a></li>
                <li><a href="MapingData.aspx">3333</a> </li>
                <li><a href="EditSchedule.aspx">4444</a> </li>
                <li><a href="LoginPage.aspx">5555</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

## .css :

```
ul#topnav
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    clear: both;
    width: 980px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative; /*--Set relative positioning on the unordered list itself - not on the list item--*/
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #CC6A11;
    height: 50px;
}
ul#topnav li
{
    float: right;
    margin: 0px auto; /* margin-right:0;*/
    padding: 5px 27px;
    border-right: 1px solid #555; /*--Divider for each parent level links--*/
    background-color: #CC6A11; /*url(topnav_stretch.gif) repeat-x;*/
    text-align:center;
}
ul#topnav li a
{
    padding: 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:121px;
    text-align:center;
}
ul#topnav li:hover
{
    background-color: #1376c9;
}

ul#topnav li a:active
{
    background-color: Purple;
}

ul#topnav li span
{
    text-align:right;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 52px;
    display: none; /*--Hide by default--*/
    width: 977px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #1376c9;
    color: #fff; /*--Bottom right rounded corner--*/
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; /*--Bottom left rounded corner--*/
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
ul#topnav li:hover span
{
    
}
/*--Show subnav on hover--*/
ul#topnav li span a
{
    display: inline;
}
/*--Since we declared a link style on the parent list link, we will correct it back to its original state--*/
ul#topnav li span a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

## .js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul#topnav li").hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
        $(this).css({ 'background': '#1376c9  repeat-x' }); //Add background color and image on hovered list item
        $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav
    }, function() { //on hover out...
        $(this).css({ 'background': '#CC6A11' }); //Ditch the background
        $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
    });

});
```

Comment: You can use Jquery to do this. See reference here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483032/how-to-get-the-selected-item-from-ul-using-jquery

Comment: hmmm ,if the link is active then i want to change the color of the `li`

Comment: My fiddle works but you need to click "run" to see it. Sorry I was not clear before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow 'tag' the anchor tag to be active, normally with an id:

```
<div style="height: 50px">
            <ul id="topnav" style="text-align: center">
                <li><a href="MasterData.aspx" id="active">1111</a></li>
                <li><a href="ScheduleForm.aspx">2222 </a></li>
                <li><a href="MapingData.aspx">3333</a> </li>
                <li><a href="EditSchedule.aspx">4444</a> </li>
                <li><a href="LoginPage.aspx">5555</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

That way it's easy to produce CSS which does something different to the active link. You'll need to set that id in code (unless you have separate files for each page)

Have a look at http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css as well, as there is a nice alternative way of doing it there.

Answer (score -1):

If you need something really simple, the following will do

[See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzKJk/) - In order to get the fiddle to do what you want you need to click "run". This will navigate the browser to "/_display/" and then you will see "display" link highlighted.

```
<style>
    .highlight
    {
       background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){
    var path = window.location.pathname;
     console.log(path);
    $("a[href='" + path +"']" ).addClass("highlight");
    });
</script>

<ul id="navmenu">
    <li><a href="guy.asp">me</a></li>
    <li><a href="/_display/">display</a></li>
</ul>
```

If the links contain parameters and so you will need a loop. let me know and I will publish here the code.

Comment: In order to get my fiddle to show what you want you need to click "run" - and you will see "display" highlighted. Wasn't this the goal? to highlight the link according to current location?